# Можно ли задать одно и тоже свойство всем инфоблокам?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Есть вот такая структура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтоб у инфоблоков было одно и тоже свойство "Показывать в слайдере".
Как я понимаю, для типа инфоблока нельзя задать свойство, которое бы передалось инфоблокам. Как же тогда быть? Не создавать же мне для каждого инфоблока одинаковое свойство, а если заказчик захочет добавить новый инфоблок, он не разберется, как создать свойство. Что можно придумать? Сталкивался ли кто-то с такой задачей? СТРУКТУРУ ДЕРЕВА МЕНЯТЬ НЕЛЬЗЯ.